# Error while building tk8.4.19-src

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

While building tk8.4.19-src by buildall.vc batch file for windows. It is showing following error:

```
rules.vc(449) : fatal error U1023: syntax error in expression
Stop.
```

I have no idea about solution. Please help.

---

Edit: buildall.vc file which is calling nmake

```
@echo off

::  This is an example batchfile for building everything. Please ::  edit this (or make your own) for your needs and wants using ::  the instructions for calling makefile.vc found in makefile.vc :: ::  RCS: @(#) $Id: buildall.vc.bat,v 1.4 2002/11/04 07:49:43 davygrvy Exp $

echo Sit back and have a cup of coffee while this grinds through ;) echo You asked for *everything*, remember? echo.

title Building Tk, please wait...

if "%MSVCDir%" == "" call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"  ::if "%MSVCDir%" == "" call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"



set INSTALLDIR =C:\Program Files\Tcl

:: Where is the Tcl source directory? set TCLDIR= "C:\Tcl\include\tcl8.5" ::set TCLDIR=..\..\tcl8.4 pause :: Build the normal stuff along with the help file. :: nmake -nologo -f makefile.vc release winhelp OPTS=none if errorlevel 1 goto error

:: Build the static core, dlls and shell. :: nmake -nologo -f makefile.vc release OPTS=static if errorlevel 1 goto error pause :: Build the special static libraries that use the dynamic runtime. :: nmake -nologo -f makefile.vc core OPTS=static,msvcrt if errorlevel 1 goto error

:: Build the core and shell for thread support. :: nmake -nologo -f makefile.vc release OPTS=threads if errorlevel 1 goto error

:: Build a static, thread support core library (no shell). :: nmake
-nologo -f makefile.vc core OPTS=static,threads if errorlevel 1 goto error

:: Build the special static libraries the use the dynamic runtime, :: but now with thread support. :: nmake -nologo -f makefile.vc core OPTS=static,msvcrt,threads if errorlevel 1 goto error

goto end

:error echo *** BOOM! ***

:end title Building Tk, please wait...DONE! echo DONE! pause
```

I am using The C++ compiler identification is MSVC 15.0.30729.1

C++ compiler using: Visual Studio 9 2008 Win32

Comment: At least provide the compiler/version you used and how you called the NMakefile. In addition, try version 8.4.20 (or even better a 8.5/8.6 version that is not end-of-life like 8.4.)

Comment: Also report the name of the directory in which you are trying to do the build.

Comment: Please see question again I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem while compiling tk 8.6.3

```
rules.vc(514) : fatal error U1023: syntax error in expression
```

which is the line

```
!if exist("$(_TCLDIR)\include\tcl.h")
```

I had set the TCLDIR macro using quotes around the path.
Removing the quotes made the problem go away for me.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at [line 449 of `rules.vc` in the Tcl 8.4.19 distribution](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/artifact/d3af0259f89d9638?ln=449), it looks unremarkable; there are many other lines before it that seem to me to be syntactically similar.

If we look at [line 449 of `rules.vc` in the Tk 8.4.19 distribution](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/55527522d4a98b27?ln=449), it *also* looks unremarkable to me; there's nothing there that screams out “I'm wrong” in a way that other preceding lines wouldn't also do.

If we look at the (mangled) code that you added, it's appears to be referring to Tcl 8.5, or maybe Tk 8.5. The equivalent lines for [Tcl 8.5.14](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/55527522d4a98b27?ln=449) and [Tk 8.5.14](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/bb3d0b5d9c07859f?ln=449) are also unremarkable. (These versions were selected because they were the current ones at the point where you did your question.) You're *strongly* recommended to not mix Tcl and Tk of different versions when building Tk (but Tk *might* load into Tcl of a later version after being built; this is more likely with Tk 8.5 and Tcl 8.6, where at least some effort into checking that this works occasionally).

In short, **I can't figure out why it might be complaining about that line in particular**.

To cap it all, you're the only person who appears to have this problem. There other people who *do* build with those files on Windows (and who are quick to complain when we make a real mistake in them) so we've got a fairly high level of confidence that it's not a problem in any version of `rules.vc` that you appear to have report. This means that whatever is going wrong, it's *highly likely* to be a problem caused by you doing something strange. Alas, there's too many strange things in this world, and the particular spoor of this one is unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
Disappeared when I made sure that directories tcl8.6.9 and tk8.6.9 are at a position with NO BLANKS in path (NOT in C:\Program Files...) AND when setting environment vars TCLDIR, TCL_LIBRARY and TK_LIBRARY , also NO BLANKS contained AND NO " around paths (

```
set TCLDIR=C:\tcl8.6.9
REM Not!!! :  set TCLDIR="C:\tcl8.6.9"
set TCL_LIBRARY=C:\tcl8.6.9\library
set TK_LIBRARY=C:\tk8.6.9\library
```

). Now compiling works.